# Why don't we add Woodin's axiom or Martin’s Maximum in ZFC axioms and show that Continuum Hypothesis is false?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I just read this amazing [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-many-numbers-exist-infinity-proof-moves-math-closer-to-an-answer-20210715/). This new article states that the paper by David Asperó and Ralf Schindler show that Martin’s Maximum and Woodin’s axiom implies each other. Note that if one of them is true, then continuum hypothesis (CH) is false. The paper states that this is closer to show that CH is false. Moreover, Godel wrote in his paper in 1947:

> the role of the continuum problem in set theory will be this, that it will finally lead to the discovery of new axioms which will make it possible to disprove Cantor’s conjecture".

Now my question: Why don't we add Woodin's axiom or Martin’s Maximum in ZFC axioms and show that CH is false and we are done. Why don't we say that continuum hypothesis is no longer true? What is left to show?

Comment: You could just as easily say, "Why don't we add CH as an axiom and show that CH is true?"

Comment: @Ted I'm not sure, but I believe that the reason why we don't add CH as an axiom is that we don't know if ZF + CH would result an inconsistent because of CH.

Comment: Neither Godel's opinion that CH will lead to new axioms, nor the idea that equivalence of two axioms makes them more "true" have many backers. For most, even ZFC is not "true", just convenient and applicable. And CH or its negation aren't.

Comment: @user777 It is known (Goedel) that CH is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: No, they show that (*) is weaker than $\sf MM^{++}$. These are not equivalent axioms.

Comment: Your linked article also presented Woodin's opinion that why we shouldn't accept $(*)$ or $\mathsf{MM^{++}}$ as an axiom because $\mathsf{MM^{++}}$ is incompatible with the natural strengthening of $(*)$. I don't understand the full detail of Woodin's argument, but it still shows there is an objection of accepting $\mathsf{MM^{++}}$ as a basic axiom.

Comment: @Brian No, $(*)$ is compatible with choice. It can be forced starting with models of determinacy (where choice fails), but the end result satisfies full choice. As the article explains, it can also be forced from models of full choice, since it is a consequence of $\mathsf{MM}^{++}$.

Comment: @Andres Fair enough, and thanks.  I'll delete my former comment so my misunderstanding doesn't detract further.